# I cannot run INSERT INTO function with the data got from HTML form

Tags: php, html

This is my HTML form:

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" action="upload.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

                <div class="col1">

                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  <br><br>
                  <INPUT type="text" name="Name" value="Full name:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Full name:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Full name:' ) this.value=''">
                  <div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT type="text" name="Email" value="Your email:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your email:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Your email:' ) this.value=''"><div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT type="text" name="University" value="University, College or Institute:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='University, College or Institute:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='University, College or Institute:' ) this.value=''">
                  <div class="clear"></div></div>

                  <div class="col1 pad_left5"><br>
                  <h4>Please write about your academic research experiences:</h4>
                  <TEXTAREA NAME="Content" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value=''" 
                          onFocus="if(this.value =='' ) this.value=''"></TEXTAREA>
                  <div class="clear"></div></div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>


                  <br><h4>Upload your photo (200 x 200):</h4><br>
                  <INPUT type = "file" name="Picture" id = "picture" lang="en">
                  <div class="clear"></div><br>

                  <h4>Please upload your academic publications under one folder as a compressed file:</h4><br>
                  <INPUT type = "file" name="Publications" id = "Publication" lang="en">
                  <div class="clear"></div><br>

                  <div class="box">
                  <div class="services1">
                  <h4>GPA</h4><br>
                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="GPA" value="GPA:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='GPA:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='GPA:' ) this.value=''">

                  <div class="clear"></div><br>

                  <h4>IELTS</h4><br>
                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="IELTS" value="IELTS Score:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='IELTS Score:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='IELTS Score:' ) this.value=''">
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="services1">
                  <h4>TOEFL</h4><br>
                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="PBT" value="PBT:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='PBT:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='PBT:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="CBT" value="CBT:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='CBT:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='CBT:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="IBT" value="IBT:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='IBT:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='IBT:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>


                  <div class="clear"></div> 
                  </div>

                  <div class="services1 last">
                  <h4>ALES</h4><br>
                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="VERBAL" value="Verbal Score:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Verbal Score:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Verbal Score:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="MATH" value="Math Score:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Math Score:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Math Score:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>

                  <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="EQUALWEIGHT" value="Equal Weight Score:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Equal Weight Score:'" 
                            onFocus="if(this.value =='Equal Weight Score:' ) this.value=''"> <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>          
                  <div class="clear"></div> 
                  </div>     
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  <INPUT class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                  <div class="clear"></div>  
                  </form>
```

An this other variables I have assigned for the values for HTML form.

```
$Name = (string)$_POST["Name"];
                  $EMail = (string)$_POST["Email"];
                  $University = (string)$_POST["University"];
                  $Academic_Experience = $_POST["Content"];
                  $Photo = $_POST["Picture"];
                  $Publications = $_POST["Publications"];
                  $GPA = (float)$_POST["GPA"];
                  $VERBAL = (float)$_POST["VERBAL"];
                  $MATH = (float)$_POST["MATH"];
                  $EQUALWEIGHT = (float)$_POST["EQUALWEIGHT"];
                  $PBT = (float)$_POST["PBT"];
                  $CBT = (float)$_POST["CBT"];
                  $IBT = (float)$_POST["IBT"];
                  $IELTS = (float)$_POST["IELTS"];
```

But when I try to insert the data to the database with the code of;

```
$record = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Students (NAME, EMAIL, PHOTO, GPA, ALES_VERBAL_SCORES, ALES_MATH_SCORE, ALES_EQUALWEIGHT_SCORES, TOEFL_PBT, TOEFL_CBT, TOEFL_IBT, IELTS, UNIVERSITY, EXPERIENCE, PUBLICATIONS) VALUES ("."$Name".", "."$EMail".", "."$FileName".", $GPA, $VERBAL, $MATH, $EQUALWEIGHT, $PBT, $CBT, $IBT, $IELTS, "."$University".", "."$Academic_Experience".", "."$PublicationsFileName".")");
```

I have problem with this code. It doesn'T insert the data to database. If you help me, I will be so glad.
Thanks...

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: looks like heaven for SQL Injection!!!

Comment: Stop using `mysql_()` and if you don't care to stop, so use this and let us know what's the error - `mysql_error()`

Comment: There is no error shown on the screen. It just doesn't add the data to the row.

Comment: @HasanSaitArslan use `echo mysql_error($connection);`

Comment: I have already used this code: if (!$record)
echo "FAIL!"; FAIL is not written.

Comment: What is "." in your insert query?

Comment: you cannot upload file using `$_POST` so the `Photo` and `Publications` won't work. You may need to use $_FILES for those

Comment: if upload works maybe you are posting code from wrong script. check PHP [POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 1):

value must be inside the single quotes '$Name'`

```
 "INSERT INTO Students (NAME, EMAIL, PHOTO, GPA, ALES_VERBAL_SCORES, 
ALES_MATH_SCORE,ALES_EQUALWEIGHT_SCORES,TOEFL_PBT, 
TOEFL_CBT, TOEFL_IBT, IELTS, UNIVERSITY,EXPERIENCE, PUBLICATIONS) 
        VALUES ('$Name', '$EMail', '$FileName', 
        '$GPA', '$VERBAL', '$MATH', 
        '$EQUALWEIGHT', '$PBT', '$CBT', '$IBT',
     '$IELTS', '$University', '$Academic_Experience', '$PublicationsFileName')"
```

Comment: ($Name =$_POST["Name"];) you don't have to cast the variable in php,remove all the casting and try...

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with casting the variable. Because I have if commandson the same page, and they work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some (lot of) quotes. try this more readable method

```
$record = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Students (NAME, EMAIL, GPA, 
    ALES_VERBAL_SCORES, ALES_MATH_SCORE, ALES_EQUALWEIGHT_SCORES, TOEFL_PBT, TOEFL_CBT,
    TOEFL_IBT, IELTS, UNIVERSITY, EXPERIENCE) VALUES 
    ('$Name', '$EMail', $GPA, $VERBAL, $MATH, $EQUALWEIGHT, 
    $PBT, $CBT, $IBT, $IELTS, '$University', '$Academic_Experience')");
```

You cannot use `$Photo = $_POST["Picture"];` you may have to handle the file upload differently. I removed `PHOTO` and `PUBLICATIONS` from the query.

**Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

**Warning:** Your code is prone to SQL Injection, try to use Prepared statements. (at-least properly escape the strings)

Comment: the file uploads won't be available in `$_POST`

Comment: I can upload the file.

Answer (score -1):

You are not wrapping strings in quotes in your query.
Try this instead:

```
$record = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO Students (
          NAME, EMAIL, PHOTO, 
          GPA, ALES_VERBAL_SCORES, ALES_MATH_SCORE, ALES_EQUALWEIGHT_SCORES, 
          TOEFL_PBT, TOEFL_CBT, TOEFL_IBT, IELTS, 
          UNIVERSITY, EXPERIENCE, PUBLICATIONS
     ) VALUES (
          '$Name', '$EMail', '$FileName', 
          $GPA, $VERBAL, $MATH, $EQUALWEIGHT, 
          $PBT, $CBT, $IBT, $IELTS, 
          '$University', '$Academic_Experience', '$PublicationsFileName'
     )"
);
```

As a good debugging practice always print out the resulting query to screen, copy it and run in your phpMyAdmin console or with mysql CLI if the error is not immediately obvious.

For example, you would have immediately seen strings not wrapped in quotes if you did that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What error are you getting? I wrapped your query in quotes correctly, if something else is wrong with your code please provide more info instead of marking my answer down.